# jQuery Toggle Navigation

Tags: jquery, css

I have read all the questions on jQuery toggle navigations but have not found my specific issue.  I am just getting acquainted with jQuery, and am using a navigation system written by someone else.  I need this for a "responsive" website I am now working on.  When the user's screen width is small enough, this version of the site menu takes over.  There is a "Menu" button at the top, and the drop-down menu appears when that button is clicked.  This is the problem:  Most of the time the nav system works fine--it saves screen real estate because the second-level items disappear automatically when the user clicks on another item, so it doesn't end up stretching all the way down a smartphone screen.  But after it has been used for a while, it malfunctions.  Either there is no reaction to clicking the button, or a click causes the menu to open and close immediately.  If I close the browser, sometimes this fixes the problem.  But obviously I cannot have a website nav system that works only part of the time.  I have written to the author seeking help but so far have heard nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a relevant bit of the HTML:

```
<div id="pattern" class="pattern">
<button class="menu-link">Menu <span>&#9660;</span></button>
<nav id="menu" class="menu" role="navigation">
<ul class="level-1">
    <li class="has-subnav"><a href="#">Parent #1</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Child #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child #2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent #2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav></div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.menu-link {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
 }
.menu, .menu > ul ul {
  clear: both;
}
.js .menu, .js .menu > ul ul {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.menu.active, .js .menu > ul ul.active {
  max-height: 55em;
}
.menu > ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  position: relative;
}
.menu li.has-subnav > a:after {
   content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}
.menu li.has-subnav > a.active:after {
  content: "-";
}
.has-subnav > ul {
  display: none;
}
enter code here
```

And this is the jQuery (which I have put in a separate file that is called just before the closing body tag--as the author of the nav system does):

```
$('#pattern').on('click','.menu-link', function() {
  $('.menu').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    if($('.menu').is(':visible')) {
            $('.menu-link span').html('&#9650;');
        } else {
            $('.menu-link span').html('&#9660;');
        }
    });
});

$('.menu').on('click', '.has-subnav a', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 772 || $('html').hasClass('touch')) {
        if ($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next('ul').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').next('ul').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for this.  This also needs more information.  Is this only happening on mobile devices, desktop, both?  A specific browser?  Is there eventually a javascript error?  Running this and clicking for a couple of minutes it seemingly works to for me, although not the prettiest javascript ever.

Comment: See the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JimD/gZWTX/) jsfiddle. It doesn't (so far) produce the issues (which occurred on IE11, FF & Chrome). I add the nav for each page with a JS script. I first check the current screen resolution. If it's large enough, the regular nav is read into the page from the JS file; if it's too small, the one I'm asking about is added instead. I have been testing only on a desktop, reducing the window until the "small" menu kicks in. I have a JS function that watches for screen resizing and triggers a page refresh when it detects one, with the nav changing if necessary.

Comment: I notice that the menu "remembers" its state when it is closed, then reopened.  So I am wondering if causing the page to reload when the user changes the browser size (as I explained earlier) could be the reason for the "confusion" the menu displays after some reloads. I know users on small devices won't be resizing, but desktop/laptop users do this fairly frequently, so the menu needs to be robust enough to deal with that. Is there a way to "kill" the menu when reloading takes place so that it would start from scratch each time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly without seeing both menus you are using.  But if you are going to be displaying two different menus in separate elements, you should put that in the CSS rather than using javascript to look at the width of the window.

Comment: An update: On one page where the problem occurred, I discovered that I had added the jQuery script twice; that was enough to make the menu open and immediately close. So that was my carelessness. On the other page, there was another jQuery procedure for a slideshow. I looked at the code in the slideshow .js file and saw the line jQuery.noConflict().  I had to look up what that meant, but when I commented it out, the two jQuery functions got along well together.  All seems to be well now.